# CakePHP 2 Kcaptcha

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Hi I want to use KCaptcha plugin, but when I add code to controller

> ```
> public $components = array(
> 'Kcaptcha.Captcha',
> );
> ```

I 'm getting this error

> Missing Database Table Error: Table guestbooks for model Guestbook was
>   not found in datasource default. Notice: If you want to customize this
>   error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_table.ctp

KCaptcha is placed /plugins and it's called from another plugin app/Plugin/Guestbook

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on error message, it is not Kcaptha problem. But you have define `Guestbook model` with no table definition for `Guestbook model`.

Try define your `guestbooks` table as mentioned on error message. It's also better to show your model definition and pieces of your controller.

Comment: It was already done.
class Guestbook extends GuestbookAppModel {

    public $name = 'Guestbook';
    public $useTable = 'guestbook';